# Calculate parent node value based on children's values

Tags: c#, tree, traversal

```
public static void SelectionSetContainment(Node<SelectionSetCheckNode> root, NW.ModelItemCollection currentSelection)
{
        foreach (Node<SelectionSetCheckNode> savedItem in root.Children)
        {
            var node = savedItem.Value.SavedItem;

            if (node is NW.SelectionSet selectionSet)
            {
                var selectionSetItems = selectionSet.GetSelectedItems();

                if (currentSelection.IsContentsIntersected(selectionSetItems))
                    savedItem.Value.State = currentSelection.IsSelected(selectionSetItems) ? CheckState.Equals : CheckState.Contains;
            }
            else if (node is NW.FolderItem)
                SelectionSetContainment(savedItem, currentSelection);
        }
}
```

I have a `Node` class which holds a `SelectionSetCheckNode` objects. The code pasted above shows how to traverse my node and set enum values on leaf nodes.

What I want now is to traverse my tree once again and set values on parent nodes based on it's children.

Something like:

```
        false
      /   |    \
    true true   false
   /   \
true  true
```

I will use my enum integer values to conclude which state is on parent nodes (None, Equals or Contains) by adding int values and compare with children count. I would appreciate any help and thanks in advance.